# Can we set size of image frame in save function?

Tags: php, ffmpeg, ffmpeg-php

Unable to set the size of image frame so I am unable to use thumbnail size.

```
$video = $ffmpeg->open($videoFile);
$video
    ->filters()
    ->resize(new FFMpeg\Coordinate\Dimension(320, 240))
    ->synchronize();
$frame = $video->frame(FFMpeg\Coordinate\TimeCode::fromSeconds(1));
$frame->save('C:\wamp64\www\woc\image_bucket\thumbnail\\'.$thumbnailFileName);
```

Answer (score 1):

If you want to generate thumbnail using command, you should try this :

```
ffmpeg -i INPUT.mp4 -an -ss 1 -y -s 320*240 -vframes 1 OUTPUT.png
```

- **ss** : set the start time offset(Screenshort time)
- **an** : disable audio
- **vframes** : set the number of video frames to record
- **s** : set frame size
- **y** : overwrite output files